# How to restart the same function after clearInterval?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a primitive counter. After its value reaches 0, some animation added and after that the timer restarts again. I'm using clearinterval to stop the function or maybe I'm wrong?
Any ideas how to do this?  Here is the code I started with:

```js
var number = 5;
var timer = setInterval(counterdown, 1000);
var $counter = $('.counter')
function counterdown() {
 number = number - 1;
 $counter.text(number)
 if(number <= 0) {
  clearInterval(timer);  
 }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.flex-box, body, body .counter {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Maitree', serif;
  background: #2A2D34;
}
body .counter {
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 100px;
  padding: 30px;
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="counter"> 
 
</div>
```

Comment: I think you can call your function inside a `while(true){}` loop

Comment: @amani nope that would create thousands of timers running at the same time

Answer (score 1):

You could simply set it again

```
function restart(){ timer=window.setInterval(counterdown(),1000);number=5;}
```

Comment: I made it, but I think there is a "better way". Not to insert the same function iside the same function )

Comment: You want to count down 5 4 3 2 1 0 and than start again with 5 right? Just let the counter count and just reset number back to 5

Answer (score 1):

Just by restarting it again and resetting the number to 5.

```js
var number = 5;
var timer = setInterval(counterdown, 1000);
var $counter = $('.counter')
function counterdown() {
 number = number - 1;
 $counter.text(number)
 if(number <= 0) {
  number = 5;
        }
  
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.flex-box, body, body .counter {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Maitree', serif;
  background: #2A2D34;
}
body .counter {
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 100px;
  padding: 30px;
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="counter"> 
 
</div>
```

Comment: thats what I am talking about. No need (I guess) to remake interval.

Comment: Edited. Just set the number to 5 again. :)